# Where Do I FInd IPCC RCP Global Mean Temperature Predictions?

Tags: climate-change, temperature, climate-data

We have written a free textbook at (http://climate-change.world).  Its main focus is on the social science side of changing emissions.  We are not atmospheric scientists, so all we want to do is to adopt and convey the IPCC RCP framework (not SCP).

One simple way to convey global warming is to plot the representative global mean temperature forecast on the different representative concentration pathways until 2200, ideally with some sort of confidence intervals.  presumably, this would be three annual time-series (low, median, high) for each RCP.  I do not want finer-grained information, e.g., at different locations, but I do want to be able to update this plot every year.

Given that the global temperature increase is at one center of the public interest and debate, I find the authoritative IPCC RCP temperature forecast (and sea level) data surprisingly difficult to locate.  I would have thought this would be front and center.

Given that our current version may be outdated by a few years, could someone please point me to where one should regularly obtain the current version of this data?